# CharsetDecoder occasionally throws IllegalStateException when called using .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(...))

Tags: java, parallel-processing, character-encoding, hashmap, illegalstateexception

I'm sometimes getting an `IllegalStateException` when calling `CharsetDecoder.decode(ByteBuffer in)`. I'm calling it from (what I think should be) a sequential `toMap` operation.

The exception describes the state of the decoder as `Current state = CODING_END, new state = FLUSHED`.

The `CharsetDecoder` is initialized with `java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()`. The decode operation is surrounded by a try/catch block. I have tried explicitly adding a `finally` block where I reset the decoder even though the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) states that this should be done at the start of the decode operation. With this change I still get the same exception but the state is described as `Current state = RESET, new state = FLUSHED`.

I use the decoder in a bit of code like this:

```java
return someMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey,
    entry -> methodThatDecodes(entry.getValue())
));
```

where `methodThatDecodes` is something like:

```java
String methodThatDecodes(Future<ByteBuffer> futureIn) {
    ByteBuffer in = futureIn.get(10, TimeUnits.SECONDS);
    return decoder.decode(in).toString();
}
```

This sometimes throws an `IllegalStateException`, which the documentation for `CharsetDecoder` says that it means the decoder is still in use. Since I am not using `parallelStream()` I'm not sure why this is happening. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) states that `decode(ByteBuffer in)` is a convenience method that does the reset and flush for the decoder and since it is called sequentially, the decoder should never be in use when I call this method.

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace? Seems an strange problem.

Comment: @LppEdd

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state = RESET, new state = FLUSHED
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.throwIllegalStateException(CharsetDecoder.java:992)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.flush(CharsetDecoder.java:675)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:804)
at <my method>

Comment: The decoder is a class field or is a local variable?

Comment: @LppEdd class field injected by guice.

Comment: Is that containing  class instance used by multiple threads? Have you tried applying synchronization to it?

Comment: I have the same problem with jboss and java 7